# Can you send a Shliach to Yerushalaim for your maaser sheini?

Tags: halacha, shlichus-agency, tractate-maaser-sheini

Is there a specific requirement for the actual owner to actually eat it in Jerusalem? If yes, is a Kezayis sufficient?

Can the owner send a messenger to Jerusalem to deliver his Maaser Sheini there for other people to consume?

Comment: See מעשר שני פרק ג משנה א

Comment: @Avrah it sounds like your comment may answer the question. If you could please elaborate the Mishna